# Get majorTicks for kendo UI scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have a kendo scheduler object:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
```

and I would like to get the value for majorTicks.

NOTE:

```
scheduler.options.majorTick === undefined
```

and looks like it has never been set.

Comment: if you did not set it, somehow it will return undefined although the default value is 60(not sure if it should return 60) but if you set it in first place it will return the value check [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/awemo/2). Also you have typo there "scheduler.options.majorTicks" should be "scheduler.options.majorTick"

Comment: For me the actual value is set in custom (and unavailable) config, so is never 60, but the value for $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").options.majorTick is never set.